# How do I check if a type is a subclass of another type?

Tags: java

I need to check if an instance of the reflection Field type, as retrieved by Field.getType() is an instance of another class that extends a specific class, GenericModel.

I'm trying something as in the following pseudo code snippet:

```
if(field.getType() "is_a_superclass_of" GenericModel) {
    ... then do something with it
}
```

How do I do this?

When I try something like:

```
field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Language.class)
```

I get a result, true, which means it is of the Language class, which extends GenericModel. However;

```
field.getType().isAssignableFrom(GenericModel.class)
```

returns false?

```
field.getType() == "za.co.company.package.model.Language"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the test backwards.

```
GenericModel.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

Comment: +1 I always have to pause before using this too - some how it seems to be in the counter-intuitive direction. The reason `field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Language.class)` returned `true` is because `Language` is a *subclass* of the field's type, not the other way around (probably field *is* a Language)

Comment: This is my answer, as you posted first! Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Yah, I have done this same mistake numerous times. I guess it's because instanceof and so on goes from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
GenericModel.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to invert the order of your verification:

```
  GenericModel.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType());
```

In this code, you ask if GenericModel is a super class of "field.getType()"